# T-SQL with subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

To achieve the desired results, I am using two sets of SQL statements as shown below.

```
select 
   convert(varchar(10),custID) + '-' + convert(varchar(4),prodID) as custprod, * 
into #tmp1 
from tbl_cust  
where year(mdate) = 2023 
GO
    
select * 
from #tmp1 
where custprod in
  (Select custprod 
   from #tmp1 
   group by custprod 
   having count(*) > 1 ) 
order by custprod
GO
```

I need to accomplish the results using a single SQL statement with a subquery.

Comment: Why don't you replace your `#tmp1` from query 2 with your query 1?

Comment: This is easiest solved by using windows function, the general idea is select * from (select custprod, count(*) over (partition by custprod) as cnt from yourtable) x where cnt > 1

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to illustrate what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
With Temp_CTE AS (
select convert(varchar(10),custID) + '-' + convert(varchar(4),prodID) as custprod
from tbl_cust 
where year(mdate) = 2023
) 
select 
* 
from Temp_CTE 
where custprod in(Select custprod from Temp_CTE group by custprod having count() > 1 ) order by custprod
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(varchar(10),t1.custID) + '-' + convert(varchar(4),t1.prodID) as custprod, t1.* 
from tbl_cust t1
inner join 
(select custId, prodId
from tbl_cust  
where year(mdate) = 2023 
group by custId, prodId 
having count(*) > 1) t2 on t1.custId = t2.custId and t1.prodId=t2.prodId
order by t1.custId, t1.prodId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried it out in [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GX49voYF)

```
SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(10),T1.custID) + '-' + convert(varchar(4),T1.prodID) as custprod ,t1.*
from TBL_CUST T1
INNER JOIN TBL_CUST T2 ON T2.CUSTID = T1.CUSTID AND T2.PRODID = T1.PRODID and t1.MDATE <> t2.MDATE AND YEAR(t1.MDATE) = 2023 AND YEAR(t2.MDATE) = 2023
```

Will not work in case of duplicate data (same date for 2 same records).
Which I think is reasonable.